Podman is always adding "`localhost" in the image name
In Podman, the default behavior is to prefix the repository name with localhost/ when you build images without specifying a full repository name.
How to get rid of localhost/ prefix and ensure that localhost/ is not added in the first place when using Podman?
Example of an image created using "Podman": localhost/myrepo/myimage
Desired Image(without localhost): myrepo/myimage

I think you can't default to not having localhost/ for image names without a registry prefix. Docker defaults to using docker.io/ (Docker's registry) and aliases docker.io/foo and foo. This make it convenient to push to DockerHub because the prefix is already there but, for other tools, there's likely a reticence to use another company's registry as a default and, in fact, providing a mechanism for images that don't have a registry specified (e.g. localhost) makes sense. You could podman tag localhost/myrepo/myimage docker.io/myrepo/myimage to add docker.io as the registry.
